# Spring Batch read different csv files and xml output

Tags: java, xml, spring, csv, spring-batch

I have a requirement where I need to read 4 different csv files. These have to be read line by line. All files have different number of columns and values.

After processing, I have to generate the output in XML.

If someone can please throw some light, that how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: what are your thoughts.. We will add points to your thoughts..

Comment: I am not very much familiar with the SpringBatch framework. I am starting it to achieve the above problem. I have gone through below 2 tutorials but still couldnt figure out to achieve the solution :
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-multiresourceitemreader-example/
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-batch/spring-batch-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch has a reader interface. You can write your own reader class which can have 4 individual FlatFileItemReaders and read them until all are done.

The writer is also an interface that you can implement yourself. You'd override the write method and do whatever you needed to do.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemWriter.html
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html